# Vue: Element responses too slow to dragover event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I have a page has basically two parts: left column and right column (much bigger area). The right column contains about 1500 rows (component) and each row contains 5 div as cells. I used to bind the dragover event on the parent element of these two columns. Every time a dragover event is fired, an overlay div should appear and cover the whole window area. Example below:

> Javascript

```js
let row = {
    props: ['item'],
    template: `<div class="row">
                   <div class="cell">{{item.value1}}</div>
                   <div class="cell">{{item.value2}}</div>
                   <div class="cell">{{item.value3}}</div>
                   <div class="cell">{{item.value4}}</div>
                   <div class="cell">{{item.value5}}</div>
               </div>
};

new Vue({
    el: '#parent',
    components: {
        'row': row
    },
    template: `<div id="parent" @dragover="showOverlay">
                   <!-- display if this.overlay == true, otherwise hide -->
                   <div class="overlay" v-show="overlay"></div>

                   <div class="left-column">Drag a file and drop</div>
                   <div class="right-column">
                       <row :rows="rows" v-for="item in rows"></row>
                   </div>
               </div>`,
    data: {
        rows: [...],
        overlay: false
    },
    methods: {
        showOverlay(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.overlay = true;
        }
    }
});
```

The code runs OK though scrolling the list is a bit laggy. But when I drag a file over the right column area, it takes a few seconds to show the overlay when dragging onto the left column only takes less than a second.

> HTML

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: You mentioned that you have 1,500 rows. I am not sure if that is causing the delay for the rendering to work. 1,500 is quite a number.

Comment: Hi Ru Chern Chong, I think you are right. The overlay responses the quicker the row amount is lesser when I tested when I saw your comment. So I'm gonna have to think about how to display my rows now.

Comment: Go with infinite scrolling if you have to

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will go for pagination as infinite scrolling is not matching the business logic in this case.

Comment: Both works. All the best!

Answer (score -3):

remove `e.preventDefault();` function; this is causing the delay